# Change all SQL Server Columns From BigInt to Int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have inherited a database I need to work with. All the numeric fields have been set to bigint (without reason they are all sub 5000).

How can I programmticaly change all the columns of big int to int? Is this possible will it cause issue with any existing constraints etc?

I only want to change tables and only in the specific database I am working on.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I need to do this for hundreds of fields I am looking for something that I can run once and it will do all the updates for all table fields. I want to keep any existing constraints, null status and default values.

So basically a database wide change of bigint to int without changing anything apart from the field type.

Thanks

Comment: If  they are all sub 5k then why not use a `smallint`?  It's only 2 bytes compared to 8 for a `bigint` and can have values up to just over 32k.

Comment: System is being expanded so it is possible they will grow to that size.

Comment: if you want to do this automatically for each table, you may also want to look into the undocumented SP sp_foreachtable.

Comment: 290Mb. I can happily take the database offline to do any of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I had come across this kind of problem. I had to change `int` to `bigint`.  This is harder, but possible. It is very easy to change datatype using the following statement:

`Alter table myTable alter column targetcolumn int not null`

However if your columns are involved in constraint relationship then you have to drop your constraints then alter and then recreate your constraints.

```
Alter table myTable drop constraint [fkconstraintname]
Alter table myTable alter column targetcolumn int not null
Alter table othertable alter column targetcolumn int not null
Alter table myTable add constraint [fkconstraintname] foreign key (targetcolumn) references othertable(targetcolumn)
```

**EDIT**

If you have a lot of constraints then changing it is a real pain in the butt. If there are a lot of tables with constraints and no extreme urge at changing don't do it.

**EDIT**

Then you can do the following. Connect to Sql Server via Management Studio, right click on the necessary database => Tasks => Generate scripts.

Next => Next

[image: Necessary window]

At that point press advanced. There will be a popup. Set `Type of data to script` to schema and data. Choose whatever output is comfortable for you (file, query window)? Press ok and proceed. It will produce you a complete DDL and DML, like this:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [Zafarga]    Script Date: 02/02/2012 19:31:55 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [Zafarga] ON  PRIMARY 

GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [Zafarga].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET  ENABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Zafarga] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'Zafarga', N'ON'
GO
USE [Zafarga]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Category]    Script Date: 02/02/2012 19:31:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [CategoryId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Product]    Script Date: 02/02/2012 19:31:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Category_Products]    Script Date: 02/02/2012 19:31:56 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Category_Products] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Category_Products]
GO
```

Change all your datatypes appropriately, then run.

As you said all your data is below 5000 rows. So there is no need to modify insert statements.

Be ready it will take a long time.
Hope this was useful.

**EDIT**

This will generate you a new database, so be ready to rename your original or newly created db.

Comment: .Net doesn't seem to like conversion between different nullable int types. It makes the code easier if I can have just int in the system rather than a mix of int and big int

Answer (score 2):

I think @Oybek says this in one of his addenda, I’m giving him +1, but just to be certain I’ll outline how I’d do it. (This assumes you have a lot of constraints across lots of bigint tables; if not, doing them one by one might be simpler.)

- Use SSMS to script the entire database. (That’s right-click the database in the Object Explorer pane, Script Database As, CREATE TO, and I’d to it to a new query window and save it as a file.
- Search and replace all bigints with ints. (Do this slowly, make sure you change only what needs to be changed.)
- Modify the script to create a new database (different name, different files)
- Run and create the database.
- The hard part: copy the data from the tables of the old database to the new database.

If, as you say, all the bigints will fit into ints, you shouldn’t have any problems; the hard part is figuring out how to actually do it all. There’s got to be some way to do this via the SSMS Import or Export wizard, but I’m not all that familiar with those tools. Barring that, creating a series of INSERT… SELECT… statements performed in order of parent through child tables, with SET IDENTITY INSERTs as necessary, should do the trick.

Comment: In the generate script window setting the option `Type of data to script` to `schema and data` will create all the insert statements with all sorts of `identity insert` option. Yours is an excellent answer, short and brief ))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to Martin Smith - its much simplier, than I thought:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY COLUMN OldColumn INT [NOT] NULL
```

thats all

**Old version of answer:**

If new column should not be nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD NewFIeld INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (CAST(OldField AS INT))
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN OldField
GO
exec sp_rename 'YourTable.NewField', 'OldField', 'COLUMN'
```

**OR which is mostly the same**, relaxed for nullable column - does not holds locks on system tables while performing the update

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD NewFIeld INT NULL
GO
UPDATE YourTable SET NewField=OldField
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN OldField
GO
exec sp_rename 'YourTable.NewField', 'OldField', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: What's the point of adding a new column? `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` will work fine though both will still waste space until a rebuild.

Comment: I was looking to do this across lots of fields and  tables. It's probably more than 200 fields. Anything more automated?

Comment: @MartinSmith not stated that column may or not may be nullable

Comment: @OlegDok - You can specify that in `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`. Your code is missing any locks to ensure that `OldField` is not updated by another process as well.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yep, understand it, thanx for your tips, they always valuable

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

1. Rename YourTable to YourTable_OLD
2. Right click table -> Script table as Create -> to new query window
3. adjust the script to use int and rename table to the original
4. Create the new table and call it YourTable to replace the old
5. insert YourTable select * from YourTable_OLD
6. Drop YourTable_OLD (when you're sure everything went ok)

I guess that would be quickest. If you do it column by column it needs to convert it column by column. This involves a lot of IO that could become a problem, depending on the size of your table.

Regards GJ

Answer (score 0):

id addition to the answers, dont forget to check it all the values on the columns are on the integer range (between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647).

To automate @Oleg Dok's answer you could run his solution inside a script that loops through all tables and all columns on your DB